# Как средствами Delphi взять строку

Tags: delphi

Есть поле типа VARCHAR с, многострочными данными в ячейке. Данные, к примеру, такие:

> "Сидела птичка на лугу,
>   Подкралась к ней корова..."

Это один элемент. Так вот, как из этих данных получить только первую строку (`"Сидела птичка на лугу,`)?

Answer (score 1):

1 - Здесь алгоритм очень простой. Например, можно взять varchar -a как массив элементов( mychar[i],где i:[0..n]), и проверять каждую символ, скажем на первую запятую.

```
var count:integer=0;

    for i:=0 to n do
    begin
    if mychar[i]=',' then inc(Count); 
    if count=1 then
    showmessage('Будем копировать до '+inttostr(i)+' ');break
    end
```

2 - или же можно просто pos() функцией

Answer (score 0):

Если задача "получить подстроку от начала, до первого разделителя", то:

```
result := copy(str, 1, pos(delimeter, str) - 1));
```

, где `delimeter` - подстрока, служащая разделителем.